# What is the hybridisation of trifluoromethyl free radical?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, hybridization, radicals

Having three σ bonds in a similar manner to $\ce{CH3^·}$ free radical, $\ce{CF3^·}$ should also have $\mathrm{sp^2}$ hybridisation. However, if we look at its shape, it is pyramidal and not planar like $\ce{CH3^·}$ free radical (which is $\mathrm{sp^2}$-hybridised), which signifies that $\ce{CF3^·}$ should have $\mathrm{sp^3}$ hybridisation.

But how is this possible because the three σ-bonds will bond with three hybrid orbitals? Where does the third p-orbital come?

If its hybridisation is $\mathrm{sp^3},$ then why is it?

Comment: 1.  Geometry drives hybridization, not the other way around.  2. An odd of consequence of #1 is that non-integer exponents in the sp/sp2/sp3 notation have physical relevance.

Comment: As Lighthart suggested, it is neither sp2 or sp3. It will be somewhere inbetween. Exactly where is an interesting question which I don't have the answer to right at the minute.

Comment: [This](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34976/what-is-the-geometry-of-an-alkyl-radical) question is very relevant, although *not* a dupe IMO.

Answer (score 13):

Hyperconjugation between the orbital that contains the lone pair and the $\ce{C-F}$ antibonding orbital contributes to the pyramidalization of $\ce{CF3^·}$ radical:

[image: pyramidal geometry of CF3]

In the planar geometry the orbitals are perpendicular and no overlap occurs.

#### References

1. Carey, F. A.; Sundberg, R. J. *Advanced Organic Chemistry, Part A: Structure and Mechanisms*, 5th edition.; Springer: New York, **2008**. ISBN 978-0-387-68346-1.

Comment: This is a very popular, albeit very organic chemistry, view on that matter. The explanation in terms of Bent's rule might be much easier. Also that hand-wavy argument 'repulses more' cannot be proven, and is likely as wrong as spd hybridisation in hypercoordinate molecules. The second part is actually quite nice though