# Stability of radicals

Tags: stability, radicals

I recently came across a question about the stability of radicals and this option was given as correct.

- $\ce {F2C^.H}>\ce {C^.H3}  $

And the solution was given that $\ce{FC^.H2}$ and $\ce{F2CH^.}$ are more stable than $\ce {C^.H3}$ but $\ce{C^.F3}$  is less stable. Can anyone explain why?
If it has got something to do with inductive effect then all three $\ce {F2C^.H},\ce{FC^.H2},\ce{C^.F3}$ should be less stable than $\ce {C^.H3}  $. Right?

Comment: you might also want to consider lone pair repulsion between F atoms.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/49754/what-is-the-hybridisation-of-trifluoromethyl-free-radical

Comment: @RahulVerma Do you have anything to back up that claim? Normal radicals are electron-deficient.

Comment: @Zhe: No. I don't have. As [the claim was wrong](https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2013/08/02/3-factors-that-stabilize-free-radicals/).